# JavaScript convert UTF-8 written data to ISO-8859. (Don't think URL/HTML context, but data file context)

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1, servicenow

I am currently creating a CSV as a downloadable attachment that gets attached to a record in a table. The framework itself just writes the data content in UTF-8 into the created file. It doesn't give me an buildin tool to chose another encoding. What JavaScript options do I have to encode the output stream written into the attachment with ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8?

Comment: Which ISO-8859? ISO-8859-1?

Comment: Sorry, yes ISO-8859-1

Comment: Then you don't need to do anything. The first 256 UTF-8 characters are the same as ISO-8859-1. Anything above that you can't encode in ISO-8859-1.

Comment: The strange thing is that the attachment the framework we work with (servicenow) creates gets its content written in UTF-8. We open it with notepad and german umlauts ä,ö,ü,Ä,Ö,Ü,ß are fine. We open it with Excel 2010 they get all jibberish! So our problem is Excel would guess? What exactly does Excel mess up? Or are german umlauts not part of the first 256 characters? Then I wuold still need to knwo how to convert output stream please.

Comment: You can set the character encoding upon import in Excel as far as I remember.

Comment: There're several encoding libraries in Node's [NPM repository](http://npmjs.com/). I believe some of then are pure JavaScript implementations that should work fine in browser context, just slower.